# DNS Entry configuration

Tags: internal-dns, windows-dns

Hello i am trying to setup a DNS to resolve to two different servers using ip addresses.

we currently have the following set up

```
*.domain.com A record -> Server A IP
example.domain.com A record -> Server B IP
```

This works fine however we want to be able to do the following but are unable to get it to resolve correctly

```
*.domain.com A record -> Server A IP (any other request ending in domain.com)
*.example.domain.com A record -> Server B IP (any request ending in example.domain.com)
```

in this example if i ping test.example.domain.com i get server A's Ip. Where as i would like to get server B's IP

Is what im trying to do possible? and if it is can someone please offer some guidance on how it should be set up.

Thanks

Comment: BIND or Windows?

Comment: Windows, sorry ill retag the question

Comment: I configured this in my environment and it works as expected.

Comment: creating 2 diff zone? one for domain.com another for example.domain.com should solve this problem i havent tested it on windows but in linux with bind i have something simillar for internal views.

Comment: Hello @dusan.bajic im an idiot i was pinging example.domain.com and getting server A's ip. it does indeed work as i need to ping foo.example.domain.com to get the correct ip. Would you kindly create an answer saying such so i can mark it as correct. Thank you very much for your assistance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I configured this in my environment and it works as expected.